# How do I remove a bottom bracket?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have managed to remove the threaded locking mechanism of this bottom bracket. However, I can't get the bracket out. I have tried to just bang it out, but it doesn't move. I don't know what else to do. ideas? help.

[image]

Comment: See the threads? Untwist it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the thread on the exposed cup. That tells you which way you need to turn the cup to get it out (there are multiple standards here, and one of the key differences is that some use left hand threads instead of the usual right hand). It looks to me as though the top of that cop should rotate to the right to remove it, in which case it is a left hand thread.

You should be able to fit a spanner onto the raised part on the cup nearest the camera in that photo. Preferably a large spanner with nice sharp edges on the jaws, since the flats are not very deep.

The other side possibly has a couple of holes rather than more flats like this side. In which case you can use a [pin spanner](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/park-tool-spa6c-adjustable-pin-spanner-prod15088/?geoc=au) or a hammer and chisel to tap it out. Or, [as Sheldon suggests](http://sheldonbrown.com/tooltips/bbcups.html), just put a big bolt through and use that to turn the cup.

Comment: Yeah, place you're fingernail in the groove of the cup and "unscrew" your hand.  Whichever way "unscrews" vs going tighter is the direction you need to turn the cup.  That *appears* to me to be a "normal" right-hand thread that will unscrew in a counter-clockwise direction, but it's hard to tell for sure in a picture.  Definitely use a wrench with good square jaws, since if you muck up the shoulders of the "nut" it's a lot harder to get it loose.  A well-equipped bike shop *might* have a flat wrench to fit.